# Как задать текст кнопки (JavaFX)?

Tags: java, javafx, button, fxml

У меня есть кнопка созданная в FXML и есть кнопка созданная в Controller.java.

```
<Button fx:id="answer2" layoutX="297.0" layoutY="300.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
```

и

```
@FXML Button answer2;
```

Я их объединил с помощью @FXML и SceneBuilder.

Проблема в том, что мне очень нужно что- бы текст задавался через `answer2.setText("");`, 
а не через fxml и когда я задаю текст через метод, то компилятор выдает ошибку.

GameContoller

```
public class GameController {
    //////////////////////
    @FXML private  Button answer1;
    @FXML private Button answer2;
    @FXML private Button answer3;
    @FXML private Button answer4;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    private static AnchorPane gamePane;
    private static Scene sceneGame;
    private static String url = "/com/varchenko/game_layout/GameLayout.fxml";

    public void gameLayout() {
        ChangeScene ch = new ChangeScene();
        ch.chaneScene(gamePane, sceneGame, url);
        answer1.setText("");
       //answer1.t

    }

    @FXML
    void closeApp(){
        Main.getMainStage().close();
    }
```

GameLaout.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="560.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.112" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.varchenko.game_layout.GameController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="144.0" layoutY="161.0" prefHeight="93.0" prefWidth="221.0" text="Label" />
      <Button fx:id="answer1" layoutX="77.0" layoutY="300.0" mnemonicParsing="false" />
      <Button fx:id="answer2" layoutX="297.0" layoutY="300.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <Button fx:id="answer3" layoutX="92.0" layoutY="396.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <Button fx:id="answer4" layoutX="297.0" layoutY="396.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <Button layoutX="500.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeApp" text="EXIT" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
>       at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>       at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
>       at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
>       at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>       at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
>       at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
>       at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
>       at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
>       at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
>       ... 48 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.varchenko.game_layout.GameController.gameLayout(GameController.java:38)
>       at com.varchenko.menue_layout.Controller.buttonStart(Controller.java:19)
>       ... 58 more

chaneScene.java

```
public  void chaneScene(AnchorPane p, Scene s, String n){
    try {
        p = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(n));

        s = new Scene(p, 570, 600);
        Main.getMainStage().setScene(s);
        Main.getMainStage().show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Исходный код GameController.java покажите. И желательно как-нибудь пометьте 38-ю строку.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev 38 это answer1.setText();

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.varchenko.game_layout.GameController.gameLayout(GameController.java:38) at com.varchenko.menue_layout.Controller.buttonStart(Controller.java:19) ... 58 more. Вот ваша ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Причина появления NPE в 38 строке вызвана следующим упущением:

1. Класс `GameController` имеет поле `Button answer1` и не статичный метод `gameLayout`.
2. Вызываем

   ```
   GameController gc = new GameController();
   gc.gameLayout();
   ```
3. Поле `gc.gamePane` имеет свою проинициализированную переменную
       `answer1`, а `gc.answer1` по прежнему `null`. Отсюда и NPE.

P.S.: предположение о том что автор создает экземпляр `GameController` без использования `FXMLLoader` основано на практической проверке обратного. Пример на основе следующего фрагмента выполняется без `Exception`:

```
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/com/varchenko/game_layout/GameLayout.fxml"));
    GameController gc = (GameController) root;
    gc.gameLayout();
```

Answer (score 1):

`FXMLLoader.load()`, основываясь на атрибуте `fx:controller`, создает экземпляр класса `GameController` и 
с помощью инъекции привязывает к нему объекты кнопок, которые `FXMLLoader` создает в процессе обработки fxml-разметки.

Поэтому не стоит создавать экземпляр класса контроллера самостоятельно с помощью 
"`... = new GameController()`" (этот код в вопросе не предоставлен). Именно это и запутало поведение программы,
так как создается два объекта контроллера — один Вы создаете для вызова `gameLayout()` и в нем поля-кнопки не инициализированы,
а другой, который здесь и нужен, создается в методе `chaneScene()`. Сразу за тем в `gameLayout()` происходит обращение к кнопке первого объекта контроллера через неявный `this`, что приводит к NPE.

Если хочется все-таки оставить логику метода `gameLayout()` в коде класса контроллера, то можно сделать этот метод статическим:

```
public static void gameLayout() {
    ChangeScene<GameController> ch = new ChangeScene<>();
    ch.chaneScene(gamePane, sceneGame, url);
    GameController gameController = ch.getController();
    gameController.answer1.setText("");
}
```

При этом класс `ChangeScene` должен позволять обратится к объекту контроллера, созданного `FXMLLoader`'ом.
Для этого можно хранить его в объекте класса `ChangeScene`:

```
public class ChangeScene<TController> {
    TController controller;

    public TController getController() {
        return controller;
    }

    public void chaneScene(Parent p, Scene s, String n) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(n));
            p = fxmlLoader.load();
            controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
            s = new Scene(p, 570, 600);
            Main.getMainStage().setScene(s);
            Main.getMainStage().show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как у вас происходит инициализация GameController и вызов метода gameLayout()? В классе, где привязывается fxml, должен быть приблизительно такой код и тут я добавил инициализацию контроллера с изменением текста кнопки:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/GameLayout.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    GameController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setText("OK");
    primaryStage.setTitle("Title");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
};
```

Контроллер обязательно должен инициализироваться после вызова loader.load();

Comment: У меня это есть , весь код - это не один файл. Я прорисовую несколько окон, поэтому и создал функцию для этого . Она есть в инном классе

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, код, где у Вас идет вызов метода gameLayout()

Comment: добавил , смотрите ChangeScene